# DNS unknown host resolved to some pblic ip

Tags: dns, ping, hostname

In my windows machine all unknown host name resolved to some public open dns ip address when i try to ping any unknown host name as below but for the name host name other windows machine in the same subnet show "unknown host" error

```
ping aaaasdas11223

Reply from 69.63.189.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 69.63.189.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 69.63.189.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 69.63.189.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 69.63.189.11:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds: Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

From other machine :

```
ping aaaasdas11223

Ping request could not find host aaaasdas11223. Please check the name and try again.
```

I haven't configured nothing specific to DNS in both the machines
Please let me know what could be the problem and how to resolve this

Thx

Comment: FWIW, `69.63.189.11` belongs to Facebook, Inc.

Answer (score 3):

Some providers start replying with "helpful navigation assistants". If you are not on a DOMAIN or WORKGROUP and don't have control over the DNS server you are asking I'd give the provider a phone call and ask why they are mucking with DNS.

Also you are not giving us the information you get from DNS, `dig` is my tool of choice that can tell what exactly is going on looking at the DNS site of things...

May I suggest that these kinds of questions be directed at superuser.com - It seems more a "Desktop/Workstation Problem" than system administration...

Comment: how to use dig tool to debug the problem